# beamer - tiny - itemize - itemize leads to incorrect line spacing (and font size)

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize, line-spacing

I am using beamer with tiny font size (because otherwise the text is realy huge) with `\begin{tiny} ... \end{tiny}`. At some point I am using a double itemize (so, with two levels). This has the following two unintended effects:

- The font size is changed to normal in the inner itemize environment
- The line spacing is changed (probably to that you would have in normalsize text) in the inner itemize environment and in the last item before the inner itemize environment.

Sample code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{document}

%next slide
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{tiny}
\begin{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\begin{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{itemize}
\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Solved part**

The first problem is solved by placing another `\begin{tiny} ... \end{tiny}` around the text in the inner itemize environment (corrects font size) and leaving an empty line before the end of the inner itemize environment (corrects line spacing in the inner itemize environment).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{document}

%next slide
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{tiny}
\begin{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\begin{itemize}
\begin{tiny}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 

\end{tiny}
\end{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{itemize}
\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This works but is clearly not intendend this way and is a dirty hack.

**Non-solved part**

I could not find any way to solve the second problem (line spacing in the last item before the inner itemize environment).

**Solution ideas**

- `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.55}` At the beginning of the item in question. This gives an item spacing that looks about right. But it is terribly non-generic, the .55 is derived by trial and error and I am afraid that this will probably fall apart whenever I change something.
- Set smaller document default font size `\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}`. 8pt is the smallest that is accepted and is still really large.

What would be the generic way to solve this? I am sure I am not the first one to have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use beamers own font mechanism:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{document}

%next slide
\begin{frame}{title}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\tiny}
\begin{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\begin{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{itemize}
  \item word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\end{itemize}
%\end{tiny}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```