# Creating a custom font size (redux)

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402328/creating-a-custom-font-size?noredirect=1#comment1002416_402328), I learned from @MartinSharrer how to create a custom fontsize.    It works wonderfully for except when I nest itemize lists.    For the first itemize level it works as expected, but for lower levels, it does not.      Here's an example of what happens.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\myFontLength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myFont}[1]{%
    \@defaultunits\myFontLength=#1pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\@tempa{{\strip@pt\myFontLength}}%
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
        \edef\@currsize{\noexpand\myFont\@tempa}% store calculated size
    \fi
    \myFontLength=1.2\myFontLength
    \edef\@tempa{\@tempa{\strip@pt\myFontLength}}%
    \expandafter\fontsize\@tempa
    \selectfont
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\myFont{4}{This is a test
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is a test \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is a test \\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is a test \\
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image]

Could somebody please advise how to modify my `\myFont` macro so that it works consistently for all levels of `itemize`?    If anybody as a bonus could explain how to reduce the font size by say 1 unit each time I nest one more level, thus automating this effect:

[image]

Thanks very much!

Comment: why not simply `\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont` what is the definition achieving?  Also there should be no `\\ ` before \begin{itemize}` although that is unrelated to font use.

Comment: oh just looked at your link you got exactly the same comments 3 years ago when you asked this!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with `article` class. Thus, this is probably due to the internal setting of `beamer`, see [beamer - tiny - itemize - itemize leads to incorrect line spacing (and font size)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440419/beamer-tiny-itemize-itemize-leads-to-incorrect-line-spacing-and-font-size).

According to the answer there, I suggest you do

```
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\myFont{4}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\myFont{4}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\myFont{4}}
```

If later you wish to write `itemize` in its normal size, you can simply put

```
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\footnotesize}
```

to restore the default value.

Below is the complete code. Note that I've changed your definition of `\myFont` to `\newcommand{\myFont}[1]{\fontsize{#1 pt}{\numexpr 6 * #1 / 5\relax pt}\selectfont}`, for me it seems identical to yours, but is much simpler.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\myFont}[1]{\fontsize{#1 pt}{\numexpr 6 * #1 / 5\relax pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\myFont{4}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\myFont{4}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\myFont{4}}

\begin{frame}
\myFont{4}{This is a test}\normalsize Normal size
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is a test \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is a test \\
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is a test \\
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: using the same value in both arguments of \fontsize is not a good idea, this will give a too tight baselineskip.

Comment: Change the value and write two or three lines of text to see the difference.

Comment: A factor of 1.2 is rather typical, but it depends also on the font, some need more spacing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the second argument to `\numexpr 6 * #1 / 5\relax pt`, but I'm not sure if `\numexpr` would produce an integer or a float.

Comment: \numexpr produce an integer, better load xfp and then use `\fpeval{1.2*#1}pt`